# Adding new image to Xamarin Android changes all other images

Tags: android, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I'm new to Xamarin and I'm facing strange issue that whenever i try to add new image to Resources/drawable folder of Android and referring it to shared code,all other images are getting change and starts referring  random images.
Steps which I'm following :

1. Add a new Image to Resources/drawable folder.
2. Change Build Action to "AndroidResources".
3. And referring the new image in Source attribute.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Hope its still worth not going native while having issues like this, apart from performance.

Comment: Have you tried to clean and rebuild your project? (maybe the name is the same, those are my thoughts)

Comment: being made do xamarin in work. what a pain in the ass. native is way better.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Android resource generated file was not re-generated or broken. Try Clean-Build Android project. If that doesn't help, delete `bin` and `obj` folders and try building again.